# What would be the regular expression to extract substring?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to have a regular expression to extract the value of `vector_name` in different strings. I tried the followings, but could not get it to work.

import re

```
# I want to extract the value of vector_name using a regular expression

mystring1 = "options={}, params={vector_name=get_x, default_like_count=2, seeting_id=1200, system=0 back"
mystring2 = "literal options={}, params={setting_id=1200, seed_val=22, system=0, vector_name=get_Z foobar}"
mystring3 = "params={seed_rand=1200, seed_val=22, system=0, vector_name=corodinate2, tt=lly}"

# I have
re.search(r'vector_name=([^/]+),', mystring1).group(1)
# should give get_x

re.search(r'vector_name=([^/]+),', mystring2).group(1)
# should give get_Z

re.search(r'vector_name=([^/]+),', mystring3).group(1)
# should give corodinate2
```

Does anyone have any idea what would be the correct regex?

Comment: Try `r'vector_name=(\w+)`

Comment: Great, thanks Wikitor it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[^/]+` pattern matches one or more chars other than `/` greedily.

You may restrict the chars you want to match, say, with `\w+`, to match 1 or more word chars (i.e. letters, digits, underscores):

```
r'vector_name=(\w+)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yvJICV/1)

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/qSJ6Em):

```
import re
strs = ['options={}, params={vector_name=get_x, default_like_count=2, seeting_id=1200, system=0 back', 'literal options={}, params={setting_id=1200, seed_val=22, system=0, vector_name=get_Z foobar}', 'mystring3 = "params={seed_rand=1200, seed_val=22, system=0, vector_name=corodinate2, tt=lly}' ]
rx = re.compile(r'vector_name=(\w+)')
for s in strs:
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
# => ['get_x', 'get_Z', 'corodinate2']
```

Comment: My bad I did not mention that `vector_name` can be duplicated in the same string with the same value. So I need to grab it only once. Because see this example, where it doesn't return the value correctly. 
 `ipdb> zz
'options={}, params={vector_name=get_x, default_like_count=2, setting_id=1200, system=0 back options={}, params={vector_name=get_x, default_like_count=2, setting_id=1200, system=0 back'
ipdb> re.search(r'vector_name=([^/]+),', zz).group(1)
'get_x, default_like_count=2, setting_id=1200, system=0 back options={}, params={vector_name=get_x, default_like_count=2, setting_id=1200'`

Comment: @JVK So, `re.search` is what you need since it extracts the first match. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/mYjIjY) where you only get the `get_x` value.